# Visual Studio 2015 Ctrl + D (code duplication) not working (keyboard shortcut scheme issue with Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Ctrl + D in a Visual Studio 2015 Windows10 project is not working at all.. its working in Notepad++.  I have tried to reboot my machine, and closed down Visual Studio but nothing works.

I have Windows 10 Threshold 2 and Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0

PS: it was working fine yesterday...

Edit1:

Keyboard mapping is looking good:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the keyboard mappings in settings?

Comment: Do you know the name for Ctrl + D so that I can look it up in Tools -> Options -> Enviroment -> Keyboard.  Ok its, Edit.GoToFindCombo : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**RESHARPER is/was the culprit**

How to fix:

- reset all Visual Studio settings (**Tools** > **Import and Export Settings** > **Reset all settings**)
- then go to the **Resharper** > **Options** > **Keyboard & Menus** and **re-apply the keyboard shortcut scheme**.

and now its working again!

Comment: it's worth Exporting at least some of the settings (fonts, colors, layout, etc.) before Resetting all your VS settings

Comment: worked for me without resetting the Visual Studio settings (by simply re-applying the keyboard shortcut scheme). Before resetting all your setting, check if this works for you too!

Comment: +1.  Amazingly VS got reset to Resharper's settings today for no reason, despite me uninstalling Resharper six months ago...!

Answer (score 9):

Below steps are worked for me.

1. Go to **Tools > Options >Environment >General> Keyboard**
2. Select **visual C# 2005** in keyboard mapping scheme
3. In Show commands containing, search for **Edit.Duplicate**
4. Assign **Ctrl + D** in shortcut key

Comment: Didn't have RESHARPER installed, and this setup worked for me, tks o/

Comment: ```Tools > Options >Environment >General> Keyboard``` chaged to ```Tools > Options >Environment > Keyboard``` in ```vs 2022```

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling ReSharper fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI,  If you are VS 2019 User:

**Extensions** > **Resharper** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard**

Change Keyboard Scheme to ***None*** and save, then go back again and change it to ***Visual Studio***

I was struggling with this problem for a while and this method fixed it.

Comment: Instead of switching to None and back to Visual Studio, it worked for me to press the "Apply Scheme". (Like @SwissCoder has written in a comment to an older answer)

Answer (score 0):

Goto **File**->**Preferances**->**keybord Shortcut**->On the top search **duplicate**->Double click on **duplicate Selection**->**ctrl+Shift+D**->Press **Enter**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).